# Recommendations for a google finance-like interactive chart control

Tags: .net, charts, google-finance

I need some sort of interactive chart control for my .NET-based web app.  I have some wide XY charts, and the user should be able to interactively scroll and zoom into a specific window on the x axis.  Something that acts similar to the google finance control would be nice, but without the need for the date labels or the news event annotations.  Also, I'd prefer to avoid Flash, if that's even possible.  Can someone please give some recommendations of something that might come close?

EDIT:  the "real" google timeline visualization is for date-based data.  I just have numeric data.  I tried to use that control for non-date data, but it seems to always want to show a date and demands that the first data column actually be a date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try out [Flotr](http://solutoire.com/flotr/), a nice javascript library.  It has pretty decent mouse controls and is free to use.

Answer (score 24):

How about using the "real" google finance tool from the Google visualizations project?

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Comment: you could probably generalise this solution into a server control if you were interested in reuse.

Comment: note that using google's control / API implies that you need to make your data available to google (their servers must be able to fetch the data). might not be feasible for confidential company data or intranets

Comment: @knb: This is wrong: "All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server."

Comment: Agree with gdw2, OP said he didn't want to use Flash

Answer (score 9):

This is the one you are looking for. An almost exact match for the Google Flash graph.

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index

Comment: doesn't this require that the user have html5 capability in their browser? I think lower versions of ie and firefox don't support this yet

Comment: you can use excanvas to impersonate a canvas in IE http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the the [Google vizualisation API](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html), I guess this is what Google uses on Google Finance. I had a look at a few other chart API's, but this one is free and beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

The Zoom Scrollbar sample on the SoftwareFX site looks like what you are looking for:

http://demo.softwarefx.com/chartfx/aspnet/ajaxsamples/

Comment: But this feels quite heavy and slow compared to other alternatives like Flotr or Google Visualization Annotated Timeline

Answer (score 1):

Check out [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com). There's XY Chart and Stock charts. Sure these are Flash based charts but I don't think you can have anything this nice and interactive without Flash or Silverlight these days.

Answer (score 1):

jqplot is impressive and improving every day

Answer (score 1):

Why not use this clone:

http://code.google.com/p/time-series-graph/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to respond to knb's comment about Google Finance chart but seems like there's no reply button.  Anyhow, according to this:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html#Data_Policy

No data is sent to any server so it doesn't seem like anything is fetched by Google.  Anyone have any comment as to this being the case or not?  Is it better to err on the side of safety and not use it if concerned about Google having your data?

Answer (score 1):

[D3](https://d3js.org/) is a good library for plotting very rich UI charts. One can use D3 for plotting google finance like interactive charts.

Find more exaples [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery)

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used two generic libraries with my .NET work - they both have many different charttypes which include the zooming and scrolling you're after: one is free ([ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)) the other is not ([Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/)).

I'd happily recommend them both. Dundas is better - but it isn't cheap. Zed is open source so can be quite informative to just read the code.

Answer (score 0):

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) (comercial licenses only) have a pure JS finance like chart the looks good. It is currently in Beta, though.

Comment: Update: Highcharts is no longer beta, has a free ver for non-commercial use, and has stock ticker version that is pretty much identical to the google one.